# Binding a NSTableView column titles to an array

Tags: swift, appkit

I'm trying to understand how binding works. I'm trying to bind columns of a NSTableView to an array which contain the column titles.

When I try the code on Swift Playground, I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. What am I doing wrong?

```swift
import AppKit

let titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2"]
let tv = NSTableView()
tv.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn())
tv.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn())
(tv.tableColumns as NSArray).bind(.title, to: titles, withKeyPath: "", options: nil)
```

Comment: It's not possible to bind an array, bind each column instead. The Binding Name of the column title is `.headerTitle`. It's not possible to bind to an array. The key path can't be an empty string, if you want to bind to the object iself then use `"self"`. I think it's easier to set the titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand how binding works.

I'd highly recommend to read the [Introduction to Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html). This assumes you're familiar with the following topics as well:

- [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i) (aka KVC)
- [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i) (aka KVO)
- [Value Transformer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/ValueTransformers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000175i)

> I'm trying to bind columns of a `NSTableView` to an array which contain the column titles.

Cocoa Bindings Reference:

- [`NSTableView` Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTableView-SW1)
- [`NSTableColumn` Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTableColumn.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTableColumn-SW1)
- [Populating a Table View Using Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH13-SW3)

`NSTableView` doesn't have any column related binding. The closest one is the [`content`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTableView-SW76) binding, but it's about content, not column header titles, etc.

`NSArray` & KVC:

There's no way to use `self[0]` as a key path to get a first item, etc. There're some [collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) you can use on `NSArray`, but nothing like you need.

```swift
let titles = NSArray(arrayLiteral: "Title 1", "Title 2")
titles.value(forKeyPath: "self")   // ["Title 1", "Title 2"]
titles.value(forKeyPath: "@count") // 2
```

When you read all these linked articles, you'd come up with something like this:

```swift
let titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2"]
tableView.tableColumns.enumerated().forEach { (idx, column) in
    column.bind(.headerTitle, to: titles[idx], withKeyPath: "self", options: nil)
}
```

And it doesn't make much sense to use bindings in this way. Just set the title:

```swift
let titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2"]        
for (column, title) in zip(tableView.tableColumns, titles) {
    column.headerCell.title = title
}
```